# Enmascarar datos en SQL con Data Masking

Tags: sql-server, azure, cifrado

Se tiene una base de datos, que se va a ingestar mediante Azure Data Factory, El objetivo es enmascarar datos solo de algunas columnas , esto con unas reglas de cumplimiento por ejemplo una columna llamada email, el resultado del registro debe quedar asi: xxxxx@gmail.com, Segun la investigacion se tiene una herramienta propia de SQL Server, llamada Dynamic Data Masking, su funcion cumple con el objetivo deseado, Dynamic Data Masking es mas propio de base de datos. Haciendo una prueba tratando de enmascarar el dato, tengo esto: TENGO ESTE CODIGO, NO MARCA ERROR, PERO NO MUESTRA EL RESULTADO ESPERADO

```
create CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (

    empId int,

    name varchar(100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NULL ,

    dept varchar(50) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(1, "xxx", 0)') NULL );

   

 -- insert

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(empId,name,dept) VALUES (0001, 'Clark', 'Sales');

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(empId,name,dept) VALUES (0002, 'Dave', 'Accounting');

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(empId,name,dept) VALUES (0003, 'Ava', 'Sales');

-- fetch SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE; GO
```

Comment: Hace 2 dias preguntaste exactamente lo mismo y cerraron tu pregunta por un motivo. Solucionaste dicho motivo?

Comment: @gbianchi ♦   No, aun no, Sigo revisando

Answer (score 2):

El código que presentas está funcionando de manera correcta. El único problema es que estás consultando con un usuario que tiene el permiso UNMASK o CONTROL sobre esa tabla. Lás máscaras están diseñadas para funcionar con usuarios con permisos limitados.

Te dejo un código con más pruebas para ejemplificar lo que digo.

```
-- Crear tabla
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    empId int,
    name varchar(100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NULL ,
    dept varchar(50) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(1, "xxx", 0)') NULL );

 -- insert
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(empId,name,dept) VALUES (0001, 'Clark', 'Sales');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(empId,name,dept) VALUES (0002, 'Dave', 'Accounting');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(empId,name,dept) VALUES (0003, 'Ava', 'Sales');

-- Consultar datos con tu usuario
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;

-- Creamos un usuario de prueba
CREATE USER MaskingTestUser WITHOUT LOGIN;

-- Le damos permisos para consultar la tabla
GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::EMPLOYEE TO MaskingTestUser;
  
-- Tomamos la identidad del usuario para hacer pruebas:
EXECUTE AS USER = 'MaskingTestUser';

-- Esta consulta muestra los datos enmascarados
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;

-- Regresamos a nuestro usuario
REVERT;

-- Le damos un permiso adicional al usuario
GRANT UNMASK TO MaskingTestUser;

-- Volvemos a tomar la identidad para otra prueba
EXECUTE AS USER = 'MaskingTestUser';

-- Ahora se ven los datos sin máscara
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;

-- Regresamos a nuestro usuario
REVERT;

-- Eliminamos el usuario de prueba
DROP USER MaskingTestUser;
```

Comment: Como responde Luis, el tema de "visualizar o no con mascara" es el permiso de usuario sobre dicha tabla. Mas info en [Enmascaramiento de datos dinámicos > Permisos](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions)

Comment: @Luis Cazares   ,Muchas Gracias, Siguiendo el codigo que se copartio, Ya  funciono, Gracias

Comment: @Jose A. Fernandez  , Muchas Gracias, sirve de mucho la documentacion que compartiste, Ya funciono, Gracias